# Ruby left->right indexed string collection

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a ruby collection that supports a left->right index on strings similar to any database string index.  The purpose would be fast retrieval of strings by a prefix of that string.  I know that this could be done by hand using a tree but I'm looking for a built-in ruby method...

For example, given a collection containing the word "tomato", a search by "tom" would produce that word without having to do a full scan of the collection.

Comment: Can you give an example with another word to clarify?

Comment: Same as if you had a db table with 1 column 'name' of type string with an index on it.  If you did a query like: "select * from table where name like 'tom%'" this would be very efficient thanks to the index.  A typical hash or array does not give you this type of index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is `abbrev`:

```
require 'abbrev'
wordlist = [
"smooth", "snail", "sneak", "snooze", "snore", "snow", "snowball",
"snowflake", "snowman", "soak", "soap", "sofa", "soil", "someone", "somewhere"
].abbrev
```

It results in a hash:

```
{"smoot"=>"smooth", "smoo"=>"smooth", "smo"=>"smooth", "sm"=>"smooth",
"snai"=>"snail", "sna"=>"snail", "snea"=>"sneak", "sne"=>"sneak",
"snooz"=>"snooze", "snoo"=>"snooze", "snor"=>"snore", "snowbal"=>"snowball",
"snowba"=>"snowball", "snowb"=>"snowball", "snowflak"=>"snowflake",
"snowfla"=>"snowflake", "snowfl"=>"snowflake", "snowf"=>"snowflake",
"snowma"=>"snowman", "snowm"=>"snowman", "sof"=>"sofa", "soi"=>"soil",
"someon"=>"someone", "someo"=>"someone", "somewher"=>"somewhere",
"somewhe"=>"somewhere", "somewh"=>"somewhere", "somew"=>"somewhere",
"smooth"=>"smooth", "snail"=>"snail", "sneak"=>"sneak", "snooze"=>"snooze",
"snore"=>"snore", "snow"=>"snow", "snowball"=>"snowball", "snowflake"=>"snowflake",
"snowman"=>"snowman", "soak"=>"soak", "soap"=>"soap", "sofa"=>"sofa", 
"soil"=>"soil", "someone"=>"someone", "somewhere"=>"somewhere"}
```

Comment: Hmm, never thought of it that way.  This would work but is less efficient (in terms of memory usage) than what I was looking for which would be something most likely backed by a binary search tree...  I will accept though if nothing else comes in.

Answer (score 0):

What about using sort against a pre-sorted list for efficiently achieving the starting point for comparison, then doing regex match for a few words to follow?

```
# Using steenslag's list
$list = %w[
    smooth snail sneak snooze snore snow snowball
    snowflake snowman soak soap sofa soil someone somewhere
].sort!

def left_match str
    return [] unless i = $list.index{|w| str <= w}
    matches = []
    re = /\A#{str}/
    while w = $list[i] and w =~ re
        matches.push(w)
        i += 1
    end
    matches
end
```

This example:

```
p left_match("snow")
```

will return

```
["snow", "snowball", "snowflake", "snowman"]
```

Here, `index` is used to find `"snow"` from a sorted list, and regex match is attempted only five times (four success, and one failure), which should not be much load. And the match using regex is not  affected by the size of the list.